# React - Sharing state and methods between sibiling components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is somewhat of a design or react patterns related question but I'm trying to figure out the best way to share sate and methods across different children.

I have a small app where the navigation from step to step and actual form data are rendered and handled in different sibling components. [This](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharing-children-state-0xhpo) is a codesandbox of roughly how the app functions.

What I was trying to figure out is the best way to share state between the sibling components. For instance, in the app linked above I need to validate the input from `<AppStepOne />` when `next` is clicked and then move to `<AppStepTwo />`. Ideally I don't want to just have all the state live in the top level `ExampleApp` because there are a decent amount of steps and that can get ugly really fast.

The other though I had which I wanted to get some input on what using the react context api. I haven't worked with it before so I wanted to get some idea as if it's something that could possible work as clean solution for this.

Code for app above:

```
const ExampleApp = () => {
  const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState(1);

  const getCurrentAppStep = () => {
    switch (currentStep) {
      case 1:
        return {
          app: <AppStepOne />,
          navigation: (
            <AppNavigation onNext={() => setCurrentStep(currentStep + 1)} />
          )
        };
      case 2:
        return {
          app: <AppStepTwo />,
          navigation: (
            <AppNavigation onNext={() => setCurrentStep(currentStep + 1)} />
          )
        };
      default:
        return {
          app: <AppStepOne />,
          navigation: (
            <AppNavigation onNext={() => setCurrentStep(currentStep + 1)} />
          )
        };
    }
  };

  const myAppStep = getCurrentAppStep();

  return (
    <div>
      <ParentComp>
        <ChildOne>{myAppStep.app}</ChildOne>
        <ChildTwo>{myAppStep.navigation}</ChildTwo>
      </ParentComp>
    </div>
  );
};

const ParentComp = ({ children }) => {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
};

const ChildOne = ({ children }) => {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
};

const ChildTwo = ({ children }) => {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
};

const AppStepOne = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  return (
    <div>
      Name: <input onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
};

const AppStepTwo = () => {
  const [zipcode, setZipCode] = useState("");
  return (
    <div>
      Zipcode: <input onChange={(e) => setZipCode(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
};

const AppNavigation = ({ onNext }) => {
  return <button onClick={onNext}>Next</button>;
};
```

Comment: By reading your question title, I would suggest: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: I'm aware of it. I did mention in my question that I'm not a big fan of that approach just because with slightly larger apps that starts getting messy. Was looking to see if there were better alternatives.

Comment: @bos570 so you have probably to introduce some state management libs (redux, mobx, recoil, …). "Vanilla" React is quite simple, the lifting-up state if the way to go with it.

Comment: Ok. As [keul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66246426/react-sharing-state-and-methods-between-sibiling-components?noredirect=1#comment117121094_66246426) suggested, you can share data between your components using a *state management* solution.

Comment: What about using context?
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html
I think it works well for smallish (to mid size) applications and is a bit less boilerplate than redux (&co)

Comment: @flynorc that's what I was thinking. Is context api suitable for also passing different methods like for instance a validation method if I need it. I'm assuming this should work?

Comment: Yes, context would work, but beware about performance issues.

Comment: @bos570 - you can also pass methods. I would suggest first going to the the official docs and trying out a few simple examples, and after that would recommend this article:
https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively
I found some useful tips for myself there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your options here are

1. having a global store (consider redux or other state management solutions)
2. having a context around your components and sharing state from this context
3. if you are familiar with hooks consider this open-source project called `use-between` it does exactly what you want with a very simple API. [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-between)